# Is there a way to avoid hard-coding a services endpoint in a mobile application?

Tags: android, rest

For example, we're developing a mobile solution and the services for that solution in parallel, so certain features can be validated for their usefulness before they are released. In our scenario we use signed android packages, but this could apply to any client application where it is undesirable to update the service endpoint by hand.

So during development, our APK points to `https://rest-dev.myapp.com/api`. Right now we have to build a completely new APK for it to point to `https://rest-qa.myapp.com/api`, and even worse our production server at `https://rest.myapp.com/api`.

When we're testing a package (myapp-qa.apk) that's not bit-for-bit the app that gets released to the customer (myapp-release.apk) we are taking a huge risk (even though we know internally that it "should" be the same code, just re-compiled and packaged).

How has this problem been solved before?

**EDIT** Interesting solutions so far. What if I added the constraint that the services could be hosted by the customer and we have no knowledge of the endpoint URL at compile time? :-)

Comment: you could have a service that gives you the end point to all other services, depending on various parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind your end user seeing what the end point is, then you can simply use shared preferences (or any other way of storing data).  I used this technique in my last app.

Use a `PreferenceActivity` with a simle `EditTextPreference` for the end point.  Set the default value to be your production end point.  Then when you test, change the value to the testing end point.

When you actually need to connect, read the shared preference value (with default being your production one) and use it.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this, depending on what you want.  One way is to check the BuildConfig.DEBUG and .RELEASE variables and pick the end point programaticly based on those.  Another way is to provide a selector in the app allowing you to hit any of the end points depending on some setting (presence/absence of a shared preference or file is a good way of doing this).